# AnyLogic Select Output Issue

Tags: anylogic

I'm pretty new to AnyLogic and I want to know how I formulate my condition in the Select Output block. Regarding my queue, I have a maximum capacity of 2, and if the queue is full, the new arriving customer has to leave, and therefore does not wait, so this would be a lost customer. Can anyone help me out here?
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6L7u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `queue.size()<2`

Please first try to work through the step-by-step tutorials as this is, indeed, very basic ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, if I had the time, I would go step-by-step, but I'm pressed for time at this stage:/ could you then tell me how I would calculate the mean rate at which customers are lost?

Comment: Please always open new questions for new questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oh, and please flag good answers as useful (up arrow next to the reply). Helps future users with similar issues